# How to join in table column?

Tags: sql, command

I want to updated value in database column. Column value update database1. So database 1 and database 2 compare and database 1 update new value.

Sample data:

- Table 1: column names `ID` AND `BranchName`
- Table 2: column names `ID` AND `BranchName`

Table 1:

```
 ID      BranchName
---------------------
 01      Doctor
 02      Teacher
```

Table 2:

```
ID      BranchName
--------------------
01      Dentist
02      Teacher
```

New sample data:

```
ID      BranchName
--------------------
01      Dentist
02      Teacher
```

How to write change new value query?

Comment: Without knowing the database, the question can't really be answered.  It can't even be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
                UPDATE Database1
                SET Database1.BranchName = Database2.BranchName,
                FROM Database1 JOIN Database2 
                ON Database1.id = Database2.id
```

Try this,Hope this help you

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.